# All heroku apps are offline after Maintenance

Tags: heroku

They said there is a Maintenance : https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1019

But after maintenance, all my apps are offline:
[image]

I used this form https://www.heroku.com/critical to contact but no replay

I have millions of iOS users. They will delete my apps.

Anyone knows anything please help

**===== UPDATE ======**

All my OLD applications are offline:
[image]
**SOLUTION:**

Anyone who got the same problems like me, you must clone your old projects, new projects are OK but old projects don't work.

**Important:** you MUST remove your old domains and add them again to make them work

Comment: The status you linked was posted 6 days ago. There was an incident some minutes ago: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1026

Comment: NO downvoter. Please read carefully, "Heroku Data maintenance on January 18, 2017 from 19:00 UTC to 19:30 UTC", they just finished. And I just create new Application, it's OK, but all old applications are offline. I will show evidents

Comment: Ok, I have misreaden the message, sorry. But *January 18, 2017 from 19:00 UTC* will start in about 22 hours. So you may have a problem but it looks like it's not related to this scheduled maintenance.

Comment: Do you want us to _guess_ what the problem is, or are you going to give us some information to go on? What do your logs say?

Comment: @A.L OK, I'm wrong about timezone. But I'm sure heroku just make something their system. My servers were down. Terrible day. I don't want anyone get this problem like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who got the same problems like me, you must clone your old projects, new projects are OK but old projects don't work.

Important: you MUST remove your old domains and add them again to make them work

**===== UPDATE ======**

Now, heroku changed the way to add domain

**NEW DNS Target** = .herokudns.com

OLD DNS Target = .herokuapp.com **(no longer to use)**

I've just change CNAME record of my domains, and all my apps work.

I hope this post is useful for anyone got the same issue.

My servers were down about 2h, and I lost a lot of iOS users. :(((

Comment: I would like to add, when you're using the new DNS on Namecheap, you'll need to set "Host" to "www" and "Value" to "www.<domain>.herokudns.com." Previously, I was able to omit the "www" in the value section, but this is no longer the case. It is required.